# Duplicate rows in Python

Tags: python

I have the following Excel file that contains:

```
Aircraft    Position    Serial_Num   Date
XYZF         RH           12345      2019/01/29
XYZF         LH           67890      2019/01/29
```

I want my code to the following, take each line, and duplicate it using the start date +1 until a specific date.

My desired output:

```
Aircraft    Position    Serial_Num   Date
XYZF         RH           12345      2019/01/29
XYZF         RH           12345      2019/01/30
XYZF         RH           12345      2019/01/31
```

And the same thing for Position LH.

How can I do that? What functions and logic should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You have certain `end_date`, and you want each row to repeat as many times, as much it misses days to this `end_date` - each consecutive row having `Date` store the consecutive days, the last row having `end_date`.

I'm also assuming you've read your excel file into `pandas` dataframe called `df`. In case you didn't - try:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

This will do the trick for you (you can easily tweak it to get the same as per `start_date` - I kind of followed what you showed as the desired output - hence the `end_date`):

```py
# in case, if it's not already done:
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

end_date=pd.to_datetime("2019-01-31")

rept=(end_date-df['Date'])//np.timedelta64(1, 'D')+1

df=df.loc[df.index.repeat(rept)]

df['Date']=df['Date'].add(pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='D'))

df=df.reset_index()
```

Outputs:

```py
   index Aircraft Position Serial_Num       Date
0      0     XYZF       RH      12345 2019-01-29
1      0     XYZF       RH      12345 2019-01-30
2      0     XYZF       RH      12345 2019-01-31
3      1     XYZF       LH      67890 2019-01-29
4      1     XYZF       LH      67890 2019-01-30
5      1     XYZF       LH      67890 2019-01-31
```

Comment: Hi Grzegorz - a quick couple of tips. For `inline formatting` only single backticks are required - triple backticks are only necessary as "code fences" to create blocks. Single backticks are easier to write and easier (for other people) to edit.

Comment: Also, I would say that in the interests of brevity, "IIUC" is not necessary. Not everyone will know what it means, especially some ESL readers. I'd say also that if there is a chance that you do not understand a problem, obtaining some understanding via the comments first is probably better. I sometimes get the view (e.g. from Meta) that "guess answers" are discouraged (though opinions will vary). Either way, technical writing is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

install pandas and then run this

```
import datetime
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame

with open('/path/to/.csv',newline='')as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    data=list(reader)
newlist=[]
def val_date(year,month,day):
    f=False
    try:
        t=datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
        f=True
    except:
        pass
    return f

for i in range(1,len(data)):
    for j in range(int(data[i][3].split('/')[2]),32):
        templist=[]
        templist.append(data[i][0])
        templist.append(data[i][1])
        templist.append(data[i][2])
        dat=data[i][3].split('/')
        yer=dat[0]
        mon=dat[1]
        day=j
        if(val_date(yer,mon,day)):
            templist.append(str(yer)+'/'+str(mon)+'/'+str(day))    
        newlist.append(templist)

df=DataFrame(newlist,columns=['Aircraft','Position','Serial_Num','Date'])
vals=[df.columns.values.tolist()]+df.values.tolist()
df.to_csv('/path/to/save/new/.csv',sep=',',index=False)
```

Comment: @abishekParmar i tried running your code. I tells me List index out of range on the j in range (int(data[i][3].split('/')[i]. Can you help?

Comment: save your excel file as a csv file . make sure that your file has the same columns as in your question ,and the date format is yyyy/mm/dd . i tested the code again. its working for all dates up to the end of the month. you could add a for loop for other months and years. and ,it is ```int(data[i][3].split('/')[2]``` and not ```int(data[i][3].split('/')[i]```